# How to read step method contents from allure listener

Tags: listener, allure, step

Currently, I am using allure StepLifecycleListener to listen to @step. I want to get some parameters inside the method.

For Eg : I want to get
"RequestIdentifier.userservice_CreateLogin" parameter in below

```
@Step("Perform user login with retrieved OTP")
public BaseResponseDTO performUserLogin(String deviceId, String authId, String otp) {

 response = serviceManager.sendRequest(RequestIdentifier.userservice_CreateLogin, requestParams);
}
```

I can get String deviceId, String authId, String otp from StepResult getparameters() method, but how can I get some parameters inside the performUserLogin() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Step` annotation works with the method's signature, not with its body. If you want to get `RequestIdentifier.userservice_CreateLogin` value, just overload the method and pass a corresponding value as an argument.

On the other hand, it seems like a `public static` variable. In this case, you can always explicitly access it from within your `AllureStepListener`. However, it'd be an ugly approach.

I'd consider redesigning your API the way it'll work with custom types (aka entities) rather than passing raw strings. In this case, you can always compose all the required data (including statics) into your custom entity and then easily access it within `Step` annotation via `"Bla-bla {entity.field}"` syntax.